# tikz-cd: label positioning on bent arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

In the following diagram, I would like to get the label `G^F` on the dashed arrow to be centered:

[image]

However, modifying `pos` doesn't seem to work as there seems to be a "jump" between `pos=0.41` and `pos=0.42`.

[image] (`pos=0.41`) [image] (`pos=0.42`)

Is there some way to make the label centered? (Actually, I am curious why it is not centered by default or with `pos=0.5`)

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    & A \\
    C & \widehat{C}
    \arrow["{F}", from=2-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["{Y}"', from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow["{N^F}"', "{\vdash}"{inner sep=.3ex}, from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow["{G^F}"'{pos=.41}, dashed, bend right, from=2-2, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The arrow isn't symmetrical (meaning the `miday` or `pos=.5` point doesn't lie exactly at that bend where the tangent is vertical). I would just overwrite the `auto`matic placement and add `right` (i.e. `anchor=west`) to the `G^F` node. If you add `cells={nodes=rectangle}` as an option to the `tikzcd` environment (ignoring the mess that this creates) you will see that the `pos=.5` node is correctly placed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with curved arrows when they are very short. Two suggestions:

1. Increase `sep` so the nodes are farther apart.
2. Reduce the `bend` angle. I used `bend right=15` in the diagram. (Then you'll probably want to `shift` the arrow right also.)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
    & A \\
    C & \widehat{C}
    \arrow["F", from=2-1, to=1-2]
    \arrow["Y"', from=2-1, to=2-2]
    \arrow["N^F"', "{\vdash}"{inner sep=.3ex}, from=1-2, to=2-2]
    \arrow["G^F"', dashed, bend right=15, shift right=1.5, from=2-2, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just only for comparison with `xy` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=3pc{ & A \ar[d]^{\vdash}\\
C \ar[ur]^F_(.70){N^F} \ar[r]_Y & \widehat{C} \ar@/_1.2pc/@{-->}[u]_{G^F}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]